# NestedScrollView не скролит до конца

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, nested-scrollview

При прокрутке содержимого где много текста `NestedScrollView` ведет себя странно - не прокручивает до конца, где текста мало и он вмещается в экран то все работает хорошо. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Использую такой макет:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/celeb_coordinator_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/app_bar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/nav_header_height"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

            <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
                app:expandedTitleGravity="bottom|center"
                app:expandedTitleMargin="@dimen/title_margin"
                app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/celeb_backdrop"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

                <View
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/space_view_height"
                    android:background="@drawable/gradient"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"/>

                <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                    android:id="@+id/profile_image"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/circle_image_width"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/circle_image_width"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/circle_image_margin_bottom"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    app:civ_border_color="@color/celeb_border_image_color"
                    app:civ_border_width="@dimen/circle_image_border_width" />

                <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                    android:id="@+id/celeb_detail_toolbar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="pin"/>

            </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/card_fon_color"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/card_margin"
                android:background="@android:color/white">

                <include
                    layout="@layout/detail_celeb_content"/>

            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Nested scroll и Cardview перенести в detail_celeb_content пробовали?

Comment: @McDaggen, тоже подумал об этом, но еще не пробовал

Answer (score 0):

Сделай так,

```
    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/card_fon_color"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/card_margin"
                android:background="@android:color/white">

                <include
                    layout="@layout/detail_celeb_content"/>

            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>
        </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```